# Use multimedia key to start winamp

Tags: winamp, media-keys

I have toshiba Satellite pro p300 25w. The multimeia keys (start, stop, fw, prev) are associated with Winamp, that works fine. I would like the start-multimedia button to start Winamp, now it starts Windows Media Player. I believe Toshiba calls them "Easy Keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) to set those buttons up to whatever you want

> **Special Keys**
>
> If your keyboard or mouse has a key
>   not listed above, you might still be
>   able to make it a hotkey by using the
>   following steps (requires Windows
>   XP/2000/NT or later):
>
> 1. Ensure that at least one script is running that is using the [keyboard
>      hook](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm). You can tell if a script has
>      the keyboard hook by opening its main
>      window and selecting "View->Key
>      history" from the menu bar.
> 2. Double-click that script's tray icon to open its main window.
> 3. Press one of the "mystery keys" on your keyboard.
> 4. Select the menu item "View->Key history"
> 5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Somewhere near the bottom are
>      the key-down and key-up events for
>      your key. NOTE: Some keys do not
>      generate events and thus will not be
>      visible here. If this is the case, you
>      cannot directly make that particular
>      key a hotkey because your keyboard
>      driver or hardware handles it at a
>      level too low for AutoHotkey to
>      access. For possible solutions, see
>      further below.
> 6. If your key is detectible, make a note of the 3-digit hexadecimal value
>      in the second column of the list (e.g.
>      159).
> 7. To define this key as a hotkey, follow this example:
>
>    SC159:: ; Replace 159 with your key's value.
>      MsgBox, %A_ThisHotKey% was pressed.
>      return
>
> **Reverse direction:** To remap some other key to become a "mystery key",
>   follow this example:
>
> ```
> ; Replace 159 with the value discovered above. Replace FF (if
> ```
>
> needed) with the
>       ; key's virtual key, which can be discovered in the first column of the
>   Key History screen.
>       #c::Send {vkFFsc159}
>
> **Alternate solutions:** If your key or mouse button is not detectible by
>   the Key History screen, one of the
>   following might help:
>
> Reconfigure the software that came
>   with your mouse or keyboard (sometimes
>   accessible in the Control Panel or
>   Start Menu) to have the "mystery key"
>   send some other keystroke. Such a
>   keystroke can then be defined as a
>   hotkey in a script. For example, if
>   you configure a mystery key to send
>   Control+F1, you can then indirectly
>   make that key as a hotkey by using
>   ^F1:: in a script.
>
> Try DllCall: Support for Human
>   Interface Devices. You can also try
>   searching the forum for a keyword like
>   RawInput*.
>
> The following is a last resort and
>   generally should be attempted only in
>   desperation. This is because the
>   chance of success is low and it may
>   cause unwanted side-effects that are
>   difficult to undo:
>
> Disable or remove any extra software
>   that came with your keyboard or mouse
>   or change its driver to a more
>   standard one such as the one built
>   into the OS. This assumes there is
>   such a driver for your particular
>   keyboard or mouse and that you can
>   live without the features provided by
>   its custom driver and software.

Comment: It's a good solution, but I would prefer a more simple one. Since the stop, play, next and previous buttons can be configured to Winamp, I would expect that the start button also can be configured somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that winamp is your default media player. Not sure if you can set that in easy Keys, but try changing that in "Default Programs" in Windows.

Comment: That would solve the problem even better, I must have misread